# General solution of a hyperbolic second order pde

Tags: partial-differential-equations

How do I find the general equation to $$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial y} = 0$$ using characteristics. I am confused because I thought hyperbolic equations always had 2 distinct roots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Characteristics are $x=0$, $y=0$. The solution can obtained integrating the equation:
$$
u(x,y)=\phi(x)+\psi(y)
$$
for arbitrary functions $\phi$ and $\psi$.